# Pulumi: convert Aurora DB cluster from serverless to provisioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, pulumi, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an AWS Aurora RDS cluster which I am upgrading from serverless v1 to serverless v2.

The AWS documentation[1] suggests that the first step in this process via the AWS CLI is to use the `--engine-mode` and `--allow-engine-mode-change` parameters in `modify-db-cluster`.

I have confirmed that this works via the AWS CLI.

However, in Pulumi if I change my `aws.rds.Cluster`'s engineMode value from "serverless" to "provisioned" and try a `pulumi up`, the process fails ("DB Cluster already exists") as it tries to replace the cluster. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the `allow-engine-mode-change` parameter in the `aws.rds.Cluster` definition in the Pulumi documentation [2].

I am using Pulumi version 3.70.0.

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong, please? Grateful thanks in advance for any assistance.

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html#aurora-serverless.modifying.convert
2. https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/rds/cluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conversion capability was implemented recently:

> Aurora Serverless v1 supports conversion to provisioned
> You can convert an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster directly to a provisioned > DB cluster. For more information, see Converting an Aurora Serverless v1 DB > cluster to provisioned.
> April 27, 2023

from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/WhatsNew.html

So it's not surprising that corresponding support isn't there yet in IaC tools. You could raise a feature request at https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues

Comment: Would you know if there is an alternative way of converting the Aurora DB cluster from serverless v1 to v2, since the direct conversion detailed above has yet to be implemented in Pulumi?

Comment: You said you converted the v1 cluster to provisioned using the CLI. The remaining steps would be to upgrade to a v2-compatible engine version, and then create a Serverless v2 instance in the cluster. I presume Pulumi has ways to do both of those things, but I'm not familiar with it. (I script all such stuff all myself with the CLI.) Once there's a Serverless v2 instance in the cluster, you can do a failover to it and then get rid of the provisioned instance. There's not really a "Serverless v2 cluster" since you can mix and match provisioned and Serverless v2 instances in the same cluster.